# See referral Facebook page in page tab app

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-apps

Let's say i have a Facebook page tab (iframe) app that i want to connect to multiple Facebook pages, so users can enter the app through more then 1 Facebook page. Now my question is; is there a way to see if they visited the page tab app through Facebook page A or through Facebook page B?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes u can

use **page signed request** using this you can get facebook Pageid and userid

for page signed request documentation here 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: thanks! hopefully i'm able to test it later this week but it sounds legit :)

Comment: +1, this is exactly how to do it, it's linked from the [Page Tab Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/)\